# Logstash - Breaking apart a field filtered with Grok into further fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

We have log messages that look like the following:

```
<TE CT="20:33:57.258102" Sv="N" As="CTWare.PerimeterService" T="PerimeterService" M="GetWallboard" TID="1" TN="" MID="" ID="" MSG="Exit method 'GetWallboard' took 00:00:00.0781247" />
```

Right now, we use the following Grok filter:

```
match => { "message" => "<TE CT=\"%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp}\" Sv=%{QS:severity} As=%{QS:assembly} T=%{QS:T} M=%{QS:M} TID=%{QS:TID} TN=%{QS:TN} MID=%{QS:MID} ID=%{QS:ID} MSG=%{QS:log_raw} />" }
```

Inside the "MSG" / "log_raw" field, however, I want to try and extract the timestamp after "...took" into its own field. I was hoping to accomplish it by using a custom regex to extract "MSG" / "log_raw" up to a specific point, then another regex to capture the "took" timestamp and make a new field. But, when I test with online Grok debuggers I'm not having any luck. Is it even possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your CT field does not match DATESTAMP. It will match TIME. You can then use a second grok to pull the time from the [log_raw] field.

```
grok { match => { "[log_raw]" => "took %{TIME:someField}" } }
```

to get

```
    "someField" => "00:00:00.0781247",
```

I would be tempted to use an xml filter to parse that [message], since it will adjust if there are ever additional or missing fields.